# Django dynamic filtering with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to dynamically filter my querySet using the value of my input field with Ajax.

Right now I’m trying something like this:

Template:

```
<div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-body">
        <form action="" form="get">
            <input data-url="{% url 'klantbeheer' %}" class="zoekklanten" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Zoek op contactnaam...">
        </form>
        {% if object_list %}
                <div class="single-table">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table text-center">
                            <thead class="text-uppercase bg-dark">
                                <tr class="text-white">
                                    <th scope="col">Bedrijfsnaam</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Contactnaam</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Locatie</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Actie</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for user in object_list %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ user.bedrijfsNaam }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.contactNaam }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.adres }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{% url 'klantupdaten' user.id  %}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" data-url="{% url 'klantverwijderen' user.id %}" class="deletegebruiker" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#dynamic-modal"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% else %}
            <p>Geen gebruikers gevonden</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="{% url 'klantaanmaken' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Maak klant aan</a>
                </p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

View:

```
class ManageUserView(SuperUserRequired, ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'webapp/klant/beheerklant.html'


    #Query based upon contactName
    def get_queryset(self, query):
        

        #Contactnaam bevat QUERY EN superuser is vals.
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(contactNaam__icontains=query).exclude(is_superuser=True)
        
        return object_list

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.POST.get('query', '')
        print(query)
        self.get_queryset(query)
```

Jquery:

```
$('.zoekklanten').on('keyup', function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url')
    var query = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            'query':query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
                if(!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            },
            success: function(result){
            },
            error: function(data){
            }

     })})
```

I’m getting "get_queryset() missing 1 required positional argument: ‘query’ " error. I assume calling the get_queryset function inside a post request function isn’t the way to go about this.

What would be the best way to filter dynamically using Ajax in Django?

Comment: is your code really indented as shown above? If so, you have to indent `post()` and `get_queryset()` so they are nested inside the class `ManageUserView`. If they are nested there already, please fix the code indentation.

Comment: No it isn't, I fixed the indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the method `ListView.get_queryset()` is normally defined without any extra parameter, so when it's called by Django implicitly, it does not pass any value to the new extra parameter `query` you have added there.

So either use `self.request.POST.get('query', '')` in `get_queryset()` directly instead of passing it there as a parameter or add a default value to the parameter.

However using a user input and passing it directly into SQL query is risky as it might lead to an SQL injection (even though Django tries to sanitize the value).

```
def get_queryset(self, query=None):
    # either set default value for `query` here^
    if not query:
        return super().get_queryset()

    # or take the value from `POST` here instead of passing it as a parameter to the method
    query = self.request.POST.get('query')
    object_list = self.model.objects.filter(contactNaam__icontains=query).exclude(is_superuser=True)
    
    return object_list
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But when I try your 2nd option I'm getting a POST 405 error (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: Yes of course, because it is not... you know what? There will be always yet-another-issue, so instead of piggybacking here ad infinitum, you should rather open a new issue. Hint: find out what requests methods `ListView` supports.

Comment: I just want a way to dynamically filter using AJAX. What would be the best way (that is working)?

Comment: I can understand where you coming from, but again: that's irrelevant to the original question which has been solved. You can keep piggybacking here over and over again like "this works now, but now there is another problem... and look, another one... and one more".